# Galaxy S2 GPS not starting

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, gps, root-access

A while ago my GPS was annoying me with a lot of 'searching for GPS'. I had to wait at least 10 minutes every time and it holds for just 2 minutes. Then it starts for searching again.

I searched for fixes and tried one. It was done in recovery mode by flashing a zip (lost the source of the site). Since then the GPS isn't even responding! It doesn't matter if I press GPS on or off, it stays off.

I've tried to clear cache, full wipe, factory reset, nothing worked. Tried a lot of apps in the market like: GPS status and toolbox, GPS fix etc. I even rooted my phone with a new kernel, this also didn't work.

What can I do to make my GPS work?

edit: I have a Galaxy S2 (GT-I9100) rooted 4.1.2 XWLSD
Siyah kernel v6.0b5

Comment: Hopefully you have at least kept the ZIP, so you could give some additional information on that (filename, characteristical contents)? This might enable us to guess what that ZIP did; without closer information we are almost completely left to wild speculations, which would be off-topic on this site :)

Comment: No man, I have nothing from the original zip file, nor the site. Big fail, i know, but i was in a rush. But I know this: after i flashed my gps-thing, i discovered it was not for the galaxy s9100 but for the s9000. I am the smartest right? :((

Comment: You might have some look if you find the correct (compatible) ZIP and flash that over; that should cure it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got the answer:

I installed a fresh ROM (rootbox) and it helped. Weird that it didn't help before. Now I need to search a solution for faster GPS fixing.

Comment: This is an impractical solution for most users.